# How to export filtered models into an excel file?

Tags: django, python-3.x, model-view-controller, django-views, xlsxwriter

I have filtered models using QuerySet and displayed them on a page.I want to download an excel file which contains the above models on click of download button.(Sorry I am a beginner and Thanks)

I am trying to create an excel file as soon as a user clicks search, and save it to the database and download it when user clicks download via an ID.
I also tried to send QuerySet as the parameter but I don't know the regex to give to the URL.

## Views.py:

```
class SearchView(View):
    template_name = 'auto_project/search_form.html'
    form_class=ExcelFile
    qs=''


    def get(self,request):
        qs = report.objects.all()
        date1 = self.request.GET.get('date1','')
        date2 = self.request.GET.get('date2','')

        #Filter Stuff
            
        return render(self.request,self.template_name,{'qs':qs})

    def post(self,request):
        form=self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            f = form.save(commit=False)

            response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=Report.xlsx'
            xlsx_data = WriteToExcel(self.qs) #Function
            response.write(xlsx_data)
            f.file = response
            f.save()

        return render(self.request,self.template_name,{'f':f})

def report_download(request,file_id):
    response = Excel.objects.get(id=file_id)
    return response

#forms.py:

class ExcelFile(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Excel
        fields = ['id','file']

#urls.py:

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^search/$',views.SearchView.as_view(),name='search'),
url(r'^download/(?P<file_id>[0-9]+)/$',views.report_download,name='dload'),]



#search_from.html:

<form action='.' method='GET'>
    <!-- some input fields and a submit button-->
</form>

<button type="submit"><a href="{% url 'auto_project:dload' f.id %}">Download</a></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

check out [django-excel-response](https://github.com/tarkatronic/django-excel-response)

There's class based views as well as mixins

```
class ModelExportView(ExcelView):
    model = SomeModel
```

you can of course manipulate the code for your needs.